# How to restrict ItemtouchHelper to swipe only left to right

Tags: java, android, itemtouchhelper

Hi I am using recycler view and apply ITEMTOUCHHELPER its working.
I apply Logic `(direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT)` then delete item.
All of these things work correctly.

But when I swipe right side and then swipe left side. It give dX value >0.which means swiping done on right side.

If I delete an item no issue If I leave it as it is and swipe again then this strange behavior start.

**When I swipe multiple times from left side then it gives dX<0 means then it starts again working.**

**Here is my Implementation**

```
  private void initSwipe(){
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();


                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                    Cursor cursor = ((BookRecyclerAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).getCursor();
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    int  pageNo = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookMarkContract.AddsEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PAGE_NO));
                    dbHelper.deletePageNo(pageNo);
                    bookRecyclerAdapter.swapCursor(dbHelper.getAllBookMarks());
                    bookRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    bookRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else
                return;



            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                Bitmap icon;

                Log.d("dX",""+dX);
                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
                    if(dX>0)
                    {
                        dX=0;
                    }
                    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                    float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                    float width = height / 3;
                    if(dX>0)
                        return;
else {

                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                        RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                        c.drawRect(background, p);
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_rub);
                        RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2 * width, (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getRight() - width, (float) itemView.getBottom() - width);
                        c.drawBitmap(icon, null, icon_dest, p);
                    }

                }
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
```

**Here is my log cat Snippet of when i Swipping left but it gives me** **dX >0**

[image]

**PROBLEM IN ONE LINE**

**SWIPPING LEFT SIDE GIVES dX >0**

**QUESTION**

Why I am getting this strange behavior ? it feels like an app is hanging
But it is not hanging it is swiping right side even When I swipe LEFT.

Comment: Sorry I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: why do you need this x-value??? If you need a good example how to implement swipe-to-dismiss on a recyclerview, check out this article: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.q88lttfor

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX basically i know this thing but i do not want right side swipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to allow leftswipe, this is your solution:

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
     //int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
       int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START;
       return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}
```

Comment: What is dragFlags Here?
Accepted answer

Comment: Now its fix my problem  `dX < 0` or `0` not above very nice

Comment: Dragflags is the direction in which you can drag and drop an item. In this case up and down. Assuming you support this behavior. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think it is a more cleaner and simpler solution.

When you extend `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` in order to get the custom behavior, you should pass the directions for your items to be swiped or dragged, you don't need to override `getMovementFlags` since this method uses the drag and swipe directions we are about to pass. For example:

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, in your activity or fragment, when you setup your recycler view you can specify the swiping and dragging behavior like this:

```
// 0 means no dragging at all and the 2nd parameters means only swipe left is allowed
RecyclerItemTouchHelper helper = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
new ItemTouchHelper(helper).attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Now you can configure your dragging and swiping however you want. I hope it helps!

For more information you can take a look at the official documentation, there's pretty much the exact example you need:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback